# explanation of check_prime function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain me the check_prime function's working
here

```
import math
import time

start=time.time()

def check_prime(num):
    if num > 2 and num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(3, (int(math.sqrt(num))) + 1, 2): #range(start,beyondstep,step)
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
    return True


def find_sum(limit):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(2, limit):
        if check_prime(i):
            sum += i

    return sum



    # Find the sum of all primes below two million

print(find_sum(2000000))

    # confirm above is correct by solving example
    # and verifying results are euqal to that presented
    # by example
print(find_sum(10))

end=time.time()-start
print("runtime",end)
```

Comment: The function seems fairly straighforward: check every potential divisor and return `True` if none is found. The only special things it has are: 1) even numbers are checked first, which makes it faster in 50% of cases, and allows to take steps of two when iterating the divisors; 2) only numbers up to the square root of the number are tested, because that is the biggest potential divisor. Maybe you could specify what exactly is that you don't understand.

Comment: What jdehesa said. The function check_prime tests a number to see whether it is prime or not prime. Also, the other code is wasting a lot of work by checking the same numbers over and over, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: suppose I pass num=2 for the check_prime(num) function then what would be the result